# Meteor oplog tailing and performance

Tags: meteor, mongodb-oplog

What are the advantages of using oplog tailing with Meteor? 
I know of these:

- Having replica sets ensures high availability
- Oplog tailing gives improved performance when it comes to detecting changes in the DB and pushing these to the clients

More specifically, given a Meteor app where the ‘real-time’ aspect isn’t that important (i.e. not write intensive enough that a client is likely to see any data changing during their session) and also ignoring the availability advantages of having replica sets, are there any other advantages of using oplog tailing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of tailing the oplog Meteor will use polling stay in sync with the current state of the collections. This can increase the bandwitdth usage and CPU load on Mongo. Thus the final advantage of using oplog is that it results in MongoDB being more performant overall since it lowers the load.

Comment: One disadvantage of oplog tailing is that all your server instances have to process every database change.  This can become increasingly costly as your database load increases over time; you have a fixed CPU usage per instance regardless of the number of users on that particular instance.